# How to extend width in Wordpress sidebar?

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, styles, sidebar

Hi i have one issue that don t know how to fix. I want to extend right sidebar widget to right a little, so will fit to menu width ribbon. I try to fix by CSS, but seems that don t found right class for that.

```
.col-border+.col,.col-divided+.col
```

is the CSS for that sidebar block. Live demo can be seen [here](http://definitiv.cz/). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed myself using this CSS:

```
.col-border+.col,.col-divided+.col {
 display: inline-table;
 }
```